# Resolutions of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

We have a good notion of dgc algebra resolutions of commutative algebras.
Is there an explicit construction of a dg Lie algebra resolution of a Lie algebra?

Comment: Can't you just copy what Tate did? Pick a presentation; start with the free Lie algebra on the generators, add a generators $y$ of degree $1$ per relation $r$, and define $d(y)=r$. Find generators for the homology of this dg, lift them to cycles, add generators to kill them and so on.

Comment: Sure - is it written somewhere other than what you have?

Answer (score 1):

Going back to Quillen in 1969 there is a resolution adjunction between dg-coalgebras and dg-Lie algebras, which restricts to a rectification resolution adjunction between $L_\infty$-algebras and dg-Lie algebras. This is an equivalence of homotopy theories due to theorem 3.2 in

- Vladimir Hinich, *DG coalgebras as formal stacks* ([arXiv:math/9812034](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812034))

Here the resolution functor sends an $L_\infty$-algebra (and hence in particular a Lie algebra) to a dg-Lie algebra whose underlying graded Lie algebra is free on the underlying chain complex.

More details and more pointers are at

http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+dg-Lie+algebras#RectificationResolution .